# How to properly use cmd.transform_selection()

Tags: python, pymol

I have a set of 3x3 rotational matrices and a set of corresponding translation vectors for ligand poses. I have been trying to implement a python method where I translate a pose to it's origin, apply one of the rotational matrices, translate the pose to it's original location, and then apply the translation vector. For now I have been trying to implement the PyMOL API command: `cmd.transform_selection()` which takes a selection and a `"ttt"` PyMOL matrix (https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Transform_selection).

My current approach is as follows:

1.) From the original pose's (`orig_pose`), I use a ProDy function to obtain the coordinates (`org_coords`).

2.) I calculate the center; `center = np.mean(org_coords, axis=0)`, where center is a `[x, y, z]` matrix.

3.) I then use the `cmd.translate()` with the `orig_pose` as the selection, and - center as the translation vector.

4.) Afterwards I want to apply my rotational matrix and format it into the `'ttt'` matrix (e.g., `[m0, m1, m2, 0, m4, m5, m6, 0, m8, m9, m10, 0, m12, m13, m14, 1]`; see: https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Transform_selection). However it appears to apply a translation to this pose as well.

Does anyone have experience with this API command, or have encountered a way for me to transform an object given my inputs (a 3x3 rotational matrix and a translation vector)? Your help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401852/how-do-i-translate-an-atom-using-biopython-the-transform-method-is-throwing-err/77355220#77355220